# Python cannot import h2o when it's successfully installed

Tags: python, h2o

I cannot import h2o when even when it's successfully installed.

[image]

Comment: Can you please do a `pip show h2o` or `pip list | grep h2o` from your virtual environment to verify if it is really installed?
If so, please also open a Python repl and import h2o directly from there.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running different `python` and `pip` environments, such as `python2` and `pip3`. Try running `python3 2_Forecasting_monthly.py >> pyforecast.log` for instance.